# Getting all values of a list to another list

Tags: python-3.x

If i have a list of:

```
list = [{'duration': 19.8489379882812, 'enterZoneVelocity': 1254, 'averageVelocity': 815, 'leaveZoneVelocity': 414}]
```

and another list of:

```
2ndList = [249.2021]
```

How can I make it to

```
3rdList = [249.2021, 19.8489379882812, 1254, 815, 414]
```

I tried it with

```
for x in list:
    2ndList.append(x)
```

but that is sadly not working

Comment: Your list actually contains  a single dictionary, so what you need is to iterate through that dictionary values: `for k, v in list[0]: 2ndList.append(v)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
third_list = second_list + list(first_list[0].values())
```

You are taking the values of the dictionary in the first list, converting it to a list and adding the second list up front.